# Rails access calculated field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model "Job" that has 2 fields in it :id and :qty, I can't seem to access a calculated field in a query. What am I doing wrong?

```
Job.select("*, (qty * 2) AS TEST")
```

Comment: What about `Job.select("*, (qty * 2) AS test").first.test`?

Comment: NoMethodError: private method `test' called for #<Job:0x007fea2b7c6808>

Comment: And `Job.select("*, (qty * 2) AS double_qty").first.double_qty`?

Comment: Thank you MrYoshiji. I see how it is working now. I was hoping to be able to access this alias in virtual memory with a normal model accessor. I wanted to be able to sort the column by the aliased field name. It appears that I must do a calculation and hand off the entire model to a hash or array to sort it before delivering it to the view. Do you agree, or is there a way to sort the records by the aliased field?

Comment: You could do this: `scope :ordered, { select("*, (qty * 2) AS double_qty").order('double_qty DESC') }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the aliased column this way:

```
Job.select("*, (qty * 2) AS double_qty").first.double_qty
```

(`test` is a private method of Rails and you should avoid using it as an aliased column)

To use it in an order clause:

```
scope :ordered, -> { select('*, (qty * 2) AS double_qty').order('double_qty DESC') }
```

Use it like this:

```
Job.ordered
# => should trigger a SQL query like: 
SELECT jobs.*, (qty * 2) AS double_qty 
ORDER BY double_qty DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you again MrYoshiji. I understand it much better now.

Comment: I'm glad that it helped you. Have fun with Rails ;)